# Are there sandbox open-source Symfony2 projects to help learn?

Tags: php, symfony, optimization, model-view-controller, doctrine-orm

I have been reading through Symfony's documentation and with this being my first project on an MVC framework I'm taking my first steps in trying to put it all together.

Are there any open-source Symfony projects that showcase best practices to experiment around with with in terms:

- Security
- Routing
- Controllers
- Doctrine
- Twig

I know *Symfony 2.6* had the "ACME Demo Bundle" but this was very limited. I'm thinking more along the lines of Microsoft Access' "Northwind" example database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [symfony demo](http://symfony.com/blog/introducing-the-symfony-demo-application):
https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo

You can also read the [best practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html).